# Is merkle hash tree also at network level?

Tags: merkle-tree, architecture

From my understanding of the Bitcoin network, Merkle Hash Tree is used on a block level, where each transaction is a leaf of the tree (except the situation that if transaction count is odd, the last leaf is a duplicate) and the root is a mingled hash of all the transactions in a block.

Today I read this [post](https://medium.com/brandlitic/difference-between-blockchain-vs-linked-list-c8901ce1ca96), in which it says

> Merkle trees, in turn, use the hash to connect each block.

This is a bit ambiguous to me. Does that mean a Merkle Tree is also used on a network level, where each block is a leaf of the tree? I thought Bitcoin uses a linear chain architecture, similar to a singly linked list.

Is Bitcoin Blockchain a linear chain or a Merkle Tree architecture? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no merkle tree linking blocks. Blocks are connected linearly by having the previous block hash.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming!